# How to prevent top extensible navbar from being wider than body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make an always-on-top, collapsible-on-small-screens navbar using html and bootstrap 4.4.1, but no matter how much I try, the navbar always *exceeds* the body width.

This is my code right now:

```
  <section id="section1-navbar">
    <div class="row" id="div-navbar-superior">
      <div class="container col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand logo-text" href="#top-bar">Correspondencia</a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Perfil</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-comments"></i> Mensajes</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Inicio</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Salir</a></button>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle example of your code. In this code there is no problem

Comment: a horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the viewport, and when i try to see it in a mobile size screen the collapsible 'hamburger' button is also outside the body

Comment: I can't see  https://jsfiddle.net/1wq5fupb/ in your code

Comment: the scrolling bar is right there, in that very jsfiddle; thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: Do u mean x scrolling ?

Comment: I mean the horizontal scrolling bar at the bottom of the site

Comment: I added answer @dscamacho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It causes from row margins so just take row div in

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rqw9ov3y/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<section id="section1-navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="div-navbar-superior">
      <div class="container col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand logo-text" href="#top-bar">Correspondencia</a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Perfil</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-comments"></i> Mensajes</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Inicio</a></button>
              </li>
              <li class="top-nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Salir</a></button>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```